# How to capture image from webcam in Angular2?

Tags: angular, webcam, capture

I want to implement ng2-webcam for capturing pictures by streaming through webcam in angular 2, but after installation from npm I got this error:

> ERROR in ./~/ng2-webcam/lib/fallback/jscam.swf Module parse failed:
>   E:\idapril-2-5\node_modules\ng2-webcam\lib\fallback\jscam.swf
>   Unexpected character ' (1:3) You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type.

Can you suggest any other npm package for this functionality?

Comment: Have you added it in loader in tsconfig file ?

Comment: No, how to do this. Pls specify i am very new to Angular 2.

Comment: I get the same error. Anybody can help us, please?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I have included it in the tsconfig file and I get this issue. Including it is required in the later versions of angular as explained here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284